# Keep the glMapBuffer pointer alive

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering

I am currently working with OpenGL - version 4.4 and I had a question about the `glMapBuffer` function. In some other API's I have used (E.G. DX12 and VK) you can keep the pointer that the map function returns alive and flush the memory with a separate call instead of deallocating that pointer.

Is there a way to keep this pointer for a longer duration of time and updating the GPU memory without deallocating this pointer calling `glUnmapBuffer`?

Answer (score 3):

A buffer object which has [immutable storage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage) (using `gl(Named)BufferStorage` from GL 4.4 or ARB_buffer_storage) can be so allocated with the `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` flag. This allows `glMap(Named)BufferRange` to be given the same flag and thereby persistently map that range of the buffer's storage.

A buffer whose storage is [persistently mapped](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping) can be used for many buffer operations without being unmapped first. However, the onus of all synchronization for data access is now on the *user*. So get comfortable with using fences and double-buffering to [access/manipulate the data](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Persistent_mapped_streaming).